# Central locking button does not lock doors, but unlocking works

Tags: honda, crv, central-locking

On the driver side, there is a button to lock and unlock all the doors. The button did not lock any doors the other day. I can hear the usual sound of locking doors, but the pins do not go down. I can push down the pins manually and the button can unlock all the doors. Could it be the button? Locking car with the key on the driver door works, all the pins go down.

The car is Honda CRV 2001. I have checked all the 4 fuses (20A) of Power Windows in [this diagram](https://fusesdiagram.com/honda/fuses-and-relay-honda-cr-v-1997-2001.html), and they're fine. Where else do I check?

Edit: Today, everything was working fine at first (button can lock and unlock), but later nothing worked. Now, the button does absolutely nothing, not even a noise. Locking car with the key only locks driver door, other doors do not lock. The same after I removed the button, locking cars with the key does not lock other doors. So I assume not the button. What could the problem be?

Comment: I'm wondering if the central locking is thinking one of either the doors, trunk lid, or hood are not closed all the way. Sometimes vehicles won't lock if they sense this condition, but will allow you to unlock.